# Everything looks perfect, but Eclipse installer can't install it for a reason that it can't find the JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I've tried to install eclipse, but it's connected to the web page displaying the following error and I couldn't install it.

> Unfortunately the Java version needed to run Eclipse Installer couldn't be found on your system. You need the following version or a higher version: Java 1.8.0 (64 Bit)

But my JDK version is Aleady **1.8.0_231(64Bit)** and i completed setting up the environment variable.
(**JAVA_HOME**, and **Path** as System Variable)

Normally, using a different IDE like InteliJ(and it works normally on my computer) can be a solution but it's not possible because I have to submit it as a university assignment using eclipse.

What should I do?

[This is my CMD Screenshot with checking JDK version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHYYe.png)

Comment: I made installer run as .lnk file as known as shortcut button. `C:\Users\윤준영\Desktop\eclipse.exe -vm "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"`And i saw an error message `The required 64-bit java virtual muchine could not be found at the following location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin` So that I tried adding `javaw.exe`, deleting `\` or adding `\` but any thing does not helped....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else (especially other Koreans) who may be struggling with Eclipse installation, turns out that the installer won't work if your account user name is in Korean.  Specifically referring to the name that shows when you run your command prompt (as shown in the poster's image hyperlink) or at C:\Users -- if that name is in Korean, that it turns out that Eclipse installer will not work even if most recent Java is installed and paths are set correctly.

Easy way to get around this issue then is to create another local account with only English characters, and run the installer.  Not sure why this happens, but it seems to be a common pattern I noticed with the most recent version of Eclipse installer.

It seems installing Eclipse on the account with English characters only still does not allow Eclipse to run, so I have to be signed into that account if I'm using the laptop.  Maybe someone who can deal with this issue in a more efficient way can help us out?

Comment: Good to hear it worked! By any chance, did you register your username with only English characters when you reinstalled or did you keep it in Korean? If you kept it in Korean, did you have to do anything else to overcome this issue (just wanting to know for my future machines!)?

Comment: Well, my Windows username is still in Korean. It was a long time ago, so I don't remember how I set it up, but I suspect there was a conflict with the vaccine program.

Comment: Because I didn't install the security program required to use the bank web page in Korea.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with AdoptOpenJDK 13 (The `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables were correct).

The way I fixed that was simple. I created a `eclipse.ini` with the following contents in the same directory as the eclipse installer:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-13.0.0.33-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe
```

After doing that, the installer stopped complaining and I could install eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Eclipse installer Still complaining...

Comment: I hope you did change the path in my answer to the path where your `javaw.exe` is?

Comment: Yes i did,`-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\javaw.exe` and also i tried
`-vm %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: Were `-vm` and the path to `javaw.exe` kept on separate lines?

Comment: I created that file at the location of the installation file downloaded from the official site, entered and saved the contents. And also saved saparate lines

Comment: Now I am! Finally! I finally solved the problem. Seeing that the version installed in my school was an old version, I used the 2019.03version of installer. And installed it! Thank you all the answers. Perhaps this phenomenon is a bug in the installers that occurs in certain very limited situations.